# How to use markups in Org-Mode's tables?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to use regular org-mode markups, like #+BEGIN_SRC or lists, in org-tables?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. Though, maybe well if quoted as strings. Maybe explaining what you're trying to achieve would help!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to display code blocks, lists etc. in a table cell. table.el allows multi-line content in a table cell but doesn't seem to have the capability to automatic format/style code blocks etc.